# Flat Design & feature-rich office suite

Tags: gratis, linux, office

I am looking for an office suite (alternatives to Word, Powerpoint & Excel) for Linux that actually looks nice and modern, like Google Docs, but is offline, and is feature rich.

When I mean modern, I mean all clean lines and newer image, or something like Flat Design. I just want something that does not look outdated or in the past, like Windows 2003 Word or something.

LibreOffice and similar (Open, WPS, etc.) products all look horrible, and I cannot find anything via internet search. None of the alternatives available either are not free or feature rich (e.g., Write! or ONLYOFFICE), or they look like they came from the 19th century (AbiWord, etc.).

Does anyone know of a free, modern, clean-lined office suite that works *natively* offline?

To address @Sherwood Botsford, I do not need any integrated features or collaboration tools. Collaborating must be done online, so I use Google Docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67413/discussion-between-modelmat-and-jdwolf).

Comment: LibreOffice is free software. You could patch it, or pay someone to improve it for you.

Comment: Sorry, @Modelmat, but this is "primarily opinion based". How can we know what you think "looks nice and modern"?

Comment: Have you looked at Polaris Office?  I think its free for individual use.

Comment: @Mawg When I mean modern, I mean all clean lines and newer image, or something like Flat Design. I just want something that does not look outdated or in the past, like Windows 2003 Word or something.

Comment: @jmh Polaris Office looks realy nice, care to add it as an answer?

Comment: "does not look outdated or in the past, like Windows 2003 Word" - what is the most recent version of MS Office which you have tried?

Comment: @Mawg Word 2016. Anything before Word 10 doesn't look nice.

Comment: "All clean lines" and "newer image" still isn't really a specific enough description for someone who is not you to be able to tell whether a given program "looks nice" according to your tastes.

Comment: Could we end this? I believe if one of you think that something looks "modern", send it with a screenshot and I can determine the answer.

Comment: I suggest to put "with Flat Design", "not Libre Office" in the title, instead of Modern. LibreOffice is modern and whatever you like its interface or not is not changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Google apps have an extension (at least in chrome) for editing off line.  Changes are synced when the internet is available.

Google docs aren't particularly feature rich, particularly for formatting, but work well enough for casual collaboration.

In general the free stuff isn't great.  Writing a modern word processor is not trivial.  Chasing down bugs is hard due to the large numbers of interactions.

You don't say if you need an integrated suite:  Do you need live updates of spreedsheet charts embedded in word processing documents or presentation slides.

Google "MS Word Alternatives"
Google "Excel alternatives"
Google "Power Point alternatives"

Then come back and re-edit your question and give us more information about why the results of the above aren't right for you.

Also:  Specify free or paid; and tell us what platform you are on.

Comment: I don't use chrome in the first place, or chromium (I use Firefox). I do get that writing a word processor is hard, and none of the Alternatives I can find fit what I am looking for (Free, Modern). I do not need any integration of office suites (When I use Word, I copy a JPEG of graphs from Excel because it works better.).

Comment: The Google suite is usable from any modern browser.  Only offline use requires the chrome specific extension.

Free, modern, non-clunky.  Pick 1.  

You can cut a branch with a rock.  Or a handsaw.  Or a chainsaw.  The rock is free.  Tools that don't get in the way cost money.  Suck it up.

Comment: I use my device offline a lot. I can't connect to the internet all the time.

Comment: And you might not want to share your data with the cloud in any case

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Polaris Office? Advertises as a replacement for Word Office. It's a commercial product but is free for individual use.

Comment: Just a question, do you use this? Because it seems to me like it only allows the use of 60MB of files each month....

Comment: No, I don't. I just found out about it and installed it on my iPad. I've had no reason to use it.  It looks interesting and claims to be very popular but I haven't played with it yet.